# 1) Can SQLite use cluster? 2) Does SQLite have anything like MySQL Workbench? 3) How to import Excel to SQLite?

Tags: mysql, excel, sqlite, cluster-computing, workbench

1) If MySQL have cluster option, I wonder if SQLite have that option too.

2) I really haven't learn to write in **MySQL**. So I do is use the Workbench. If I turning to SQLite, does it have something similar?

3) How to import Excel to SQLite?

Comment: I would recommend splitting this into three different questions.

Answer (score 17):

On software design in general, and then on databases in particular (MySQL and SQLite are good starting points). If you're a net person, read the documentation online for both [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) and [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/docs.html). If you're a book person, go to your local library, I'm sure they will have an introduction level book for MySQL (try the "for Dummies" series, or Apress).

Software design requires for one to stop, get the info, think, plan, and only then execute.

Answer (score 1):

re cluster: No. Even the name suggests "SQL Light" - while offering the basic set of SQL functionality, SQLite shuns advanced features in exchange for being lightweight and easily portable (e.g. single-file databases).

Comment: Not true - it's more functional than MySQL, a db approx. 600 times its size! I'm not talking about tooling and all that jazz or being multi-user - but just simply being a good SQL engine.

Comment: That's very much a matter of opinion, and I'm not willing to engage in a flame war on "X is much better than Y". I stand behind what I have written - SQLite prefers portability and simplicity over number of features. This does not make it "bad," btw.